# Python Shapes Not Aligned Despite Same Shapes

Tags: python, statsmodels

I will admit that I am constantly stumped when I arrive at the common error `ValueError: shapes *value* and *value* not aligned` and with some recent code I ran with the Statsmodels library I'm stumped again.

I run `smModel = smf.ols(formula='leads ~ sessions', data=trainingRegressionData).fit()` with no issues, but at `print(smModel.summary())` I'm hit with the following error:

`ValueError: shapes (181,61) and (181,61) not aligned: 61 (dim 1) != 181 (dim 0)`

Now `trainingRegressionData` is a `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` and the Shape is `(181, 2)`, so I'm not sure how the summary spit out 61 columns, but even with that, the shapes are the same so why would the error say not aligned?

Any help with my issue above and an explanation of debugging shapes error would be appreciated.

Full Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6777963ed99f> in <module>()
----> 1 print(smModel.summary())

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in summary(self, yname, xname, title, alpha)
   2374             top_left.append(('Covariance Type:', [self.cov_type]))
   2375 
-> 2376         top_right = [('R-squared:', ["%#8.3f" % self.rsquared]),
   2377                      ('Adj. R-squared:', ["%#8.3f" % self.rsquared_adj]),
   2378                      ('F-statistic:', ["%#8.4g" % self.fvalue]),

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/decorators.py in __get__(self, obj, type)
     95         if _cachedval is None:
     96             # Call the "fget" function
---> 97             _cachedval = self.fget(obj)
     98             # Set the attribute in obj
     99             # print("Setting %s in cache to %s" % (name, _cachedval))

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in rsquared(self)
   1541     def rsquared(self):
   1542         if self.k_constant:
-> 1543             return 1 - self.ssr/self.centered_tss
   1544         else:
   1545             return 1 - self.ssr/self.uncentered_tss

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/decorators.py in __get__(self, obj, type)
     95         if _cachedval is None:
     96             # Call the "fget" function
---> 97             _cachedval = self.fget(obj)
     98             # Set the attribute in obj
     99             # print("Setting %s in cache to %s" % (name, _cachedval))

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in ssr(self)
   1513     def ssr(self):
   1514         wresid = self.wresid
-> 1515         return np.dot(wresid, wresid)
   1516 
   1517     @cache_readonly

ValueError: shapes (181,61) and (181,61) not aligned: 61 (dim 1) != 181 (dim 0)
```

Head and Tail of `trainingRegressionData`:

```
[181 rows x 2 columns]>
    sessions leads
366      197    33
367      408    71
368      404    59
369      412    60
...
544      357    58
545      285    48
546      275    38

[181 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: ALWAYS show the full traceback or at least the end of the traceback that shows where the exception occurs. Main guess, based on not much information, is that `leads` is converted to a 2-dimensional endog, e.g. if leads is not a numeric column.

Comment: @cphill Look at your sessions variable, from the error message it seems, its treated as a categorical variable.

Comment: @Josef thank you for the call out. I get how it is hard to understand without any evidence. I updated my question to include the error log and the head and tail of `trainingRegressionData`. Does that help?

Comment: Integer data is treated as categorical by patsy when using the formula interface. The simplest is to convert the data to float before creating the model. OLS does not handle multivariate endog.

Comment: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4771

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know. Thank you!